# What does @ mean in swift?

Tags: swift, annotations

I am a currently learning Swift and I am facing an issue understanding the `@` annotation that I have seen in some codes in Swift. For example: `@IBAction`.

What does it really mean?

Comment: Go through some basic tutorials online please

Answer (score 1):

> Attributes provide more information about a declaration or type. There
>   are two kinds of attributes in Swift, those that apply to declarations
>   and those that apply to types.
>
> You specify an attribute by writing the @ symbol followed by the
>   attribute’s name and any arguments that the attribute accepts:
>
> ```
> @attribute name
> @attribute name(attribute arguments)
> ```
>
> Some declaration attributes accept arguments that specify more
>   information about the attribute and how it applies to a particular
>   declaration. These attribute arguments are enclosed in parentheses,
>   and their format is defined by the attribute they belong to.

From [Apple Documents, Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html)

Comment: Please don't answer duplicate questions.  Instead, flag them as duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @AmineIng, If my answer is helpful, accept it as answer.